# ConnectionString DataSource='%' property in Delphi

Tags: database, delphi, datasource, connection-string

I'm trying to dynamically create my connection string, but I have no idea how to proceed to read the Datasource property location locally on the PC, for example when the program and db is moved from one pc to another the path  to reach the database changes so I'd like to be able to read directly from the pc where the database is now located. Basically I want to be able to dynamically get the bold part from the pc. I'm still relatively novice with delphi so a detailed breakdown of what is happening and what I need to do would be greatly appreciated.

The connection string is as follows the  DataSource is what I want to be able to receive dynamically

> con.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=
>   **C:\Users\db.mdb;** Mode=ReadWrite;Persist Security Info=False;';

Comment: That's not an exception. Please provide the actual error.

Comment: Someone made it a suggested edit for the post

Answer (score 1):

Your application should either store a reference to the location of your database (such as in the registry) and concatenate the connection string on demand, or keep the database in a standard location where it can always be found (such as the `ProgramData` folder) and point your connection string there.

In any case, you should *never* keep writable data in the `Program Files`. Ever since Windows Vista, applications have been forced write files outside of the `Program Files` folder. The application folder is strictly read-only. The only time it's ever appropriate to write to the Program Files is during installation.

### Saving in Registry...

```
var
  R: TRegistry;
begin
  R:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  try
    R.RootKey:= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if R.OpenKey('Software\MySoftware', False) then begin
      try
        con.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='+R.ReadString('MyDatabasePath')+'; Mode=ReadWrite;Persist Security Info=False;';
      finally
        R.CloseKey;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    R.Free;
  end;
end;
```

### Saving in ProgramData...

```
con.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='+TPath.Combine(TPath.GetPublicPath, 'MySoftware\db.mdb')+'; Mode=ReadWrite;Persist Security Info=False;';
```

PS - Please pardon my pseudo code, it's very rough, but just to demonstrate.

Comment: For a portable application it should be alongside the executable

Comment: @David True, but unless OP claims their application is portable, I am assuming it is just like any other software which gets installed into the Program Files. Based on location of existing database, I don't think it's portable.

Comment: That's right, I think saving in %AppData% is better